# I have one table 'user' and one table 'enc'. one user can have many enc and i want only latest date of enc. how i will do with left join?

Tags: mysql

I have one table `user` and one table `enc`. one `user` can have many `enc` and I want only latest date of `enc`. how i will do with left join?

I tried that :

```
select u.uname,e.date 
from users 
left join enc e on e.pid=u.uid 
where ulname like 'bar%' 
group by uid;
```

but it gives date that is first match with uid. I want recent date.

Is there any way to do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: use MAX(e.date) instead

Comment: it's give only one record.max(date) funciton work on entire result after left join.

Comment: Try putting the condition `ulname like 'bar%'` after join condition, like `e on e.pid = u.uid and ulname like 'bar%'`

Answer (score 2):

Use the aggregate function [MAX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column.html)

```
SELECT u.uname,MAX(e.date) 
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN enc e ON e.pid=u.uid AND u.ulname LIKE 'bar%'
GROUP BY u.uid;
```

Also your query will return error because you didn't declare table "u". I think it is an alias of users table. Also i think is better to put LIKE clause in the join condition as Kevin proposed in the comments.

Comment: it's give only one record.max(date) funciton work on entire result after left join. sorry i forgot to mention alias.i did it in my env.

Comment: If you have one uid in the result rows, then you will have one date.